# Show DB data in framework7 app

Tags: php, mysql, html-framework-7

I want to show the data from MySQL DB. The table '`mytable1`' has 4 columns: fname, lname, school and city. There are 10 rows of data in that table. So my code is:

```
DB CONNECTION

$sql = "SELECT * FROM mytable1";

$result = $conn->query($sql);

$mycontent = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
 array_push($mycontent, $row);
}

$newcontent = json_encode($mycontent);

echo $newcontent ;
```

In myapp.js I have:

```
$$.ajax({
        url:"ajaxdbtest.php",
        type:"get",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $$( ".showcontenthere" )
            .append( "<br />data.fname )
            .append( "<br />data.lname )
            .append( "<br />data.school )
            .append( "<br />data.city );

        }
    });
```

Im not able to show any data. I want to be able to show all the data from the table which has 10 rows of data. What am i doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the same code above for sending the ajax call, then you need to fix it like that:

```
$$.ajax({
        url:"ajaxdbtest.php",
        type:"get",
        dataType:"json",
        success: function(data)
        {
            $$( ".showcontenthere" )
            .append( "<br />" + data.fname )
            .append( "<br />" + data.lname )
            .append( "<br />" + data.school )
            .append( "<br />" + data.city );

        }
    });
```

Comment: what did you do different? The code is just like mine.

Comment: Inside the append function you are mixing the string with the json variables in a wrong way, no?

Comment: Oh sorry .. that was a typo. My original code doesn't have that. Thanks tho.

Comment: That's good, can you share a live sample of your project to help you find the problem?

Comment: Its working on localhost but not on the Phonegap app. I think i need to do some tweaking in the phonegap now.